# 404 deploying php site on Godaddy Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404, cpanel

I have my project in the /public_html/xxx-domain.com

and I have .htaccess file in the same directory with server.php file

having following rules

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml

but still I'm getting

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

please help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Laravel app then I suppose that you have project folder under "xxx-domain.com"

If so you must add that folder name in htacces file

Replace `"RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 "`
to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "folder_name_under_xxx-domain.com"/public/$1 [L]
```

It's a path from htaccess file to public index file
(without double quotes)

Comment: I think it is working because it is already loading favicon from the public folder, but when I added your path to the public that favicon also dissappeared.

and one more thing I also have an htaccess file in public folder

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: above is the content of that.

Comment: atleast it should load server.php if anything isn't matched.